# JQuery function not executed when the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I am quite new to the jquery development and is building a sample project to try it out. I encounter a page loading issue as the JavaScript function to call a web service is not executed when the page is loaded. I would want to execute the JS function when the page is first time loaded or subsequently displayed from the links in other pages.  Appreciate if anyone can provide guidance on this.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/demos/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/demos/docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax("http://localhost:8098/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomerList",
            {
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    // $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                type: 'GET',
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    //alert(thrownError);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data.GetCustomerListResult;

                    $.each(result, function (index, output) {
                        $('#CustomerList').append('<li data-theme="c"><a href="RewardMember_Find.html?CustomerNo=' + output.CustomerNo + '" data-transition="slide">' +
                        '<div style="text-align:center; width:80px; float:left;"><img alt="" src="images/' + output.PhotoImage + '"/></div>' +
                        '<div style="padding-left:85px; color:#575749;"><h2>' + output.CustomerLastName + ' ' + output.CustomerFirstName + '</h2>' +
                            '<table style="vertical-align:top; font-size:10px;width:100%;">' +
                                '<tr style="text-align:left;">' +
                                    '<td style="font-weight:bold; width:30%;">Member Since: </td>' +
                                    '<td style="padding-left:5px;color:#FF6600;">' + output.StartDate + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                                '<tr style="text-align:left;">' +
                                    '<td style="font-weight:bold;">Residential Loc: </td>' +
                                    '<td style="text-padding-left:5px;color:#FF6600;">' + output.ResidentialLocation + '</td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                            '</table>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</a></li>');
                    });

                    $('#CustomerList').listview('refresh');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax("http://localhost:8098/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomerList",
            {
```

This line is supposed to be

```
$.ajax({
       url :  "http://localhost:8098/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomerList",
```

Comment: I deployed the project in the IIS which I encountered about problem, but when the load the html page locally, the page is able to auto run the functions.  Any particular reason on why it is not executed when run from web server? My originbal URL above is working.